# From where does "это" come?

Tags: история-языка, заимствования

Sorry if this is not exactly about Russian language, but I do not know where else to ask.

What is the origin of word "это" in Russian language? Is it some kind of a combination of "je co"/"jest to" in other slavic languages? I suspect it must be really long time ago it formed since it is such a basic word so maybe it is more a question about history of languages.

Answer (score 4):

`Э` was originally a *deictic* (meaning **Hey, look!**) particle `есе / ѥсе` in Old Church Slavonic that became attached to many pronouns:

> Такой — этакий
>
> Так — этак
>
> То — это
>
> Те — эти

It was a common feature, present also in Ukrainian, Belorussian, and other languages, originating back to PIE.

Ukrainian:

> ген (there)
>
> ген-ген (there afar)
>
> генто (day before yesterday)

Latin

> [e]quidem (of course)

Ancient Greek:

> κεῖ — ἐ-κεῖ (there)
>
> κεῖνος — ἐ-κεῖνος (that)

Comment: is this particle related to "ecce homo" ?

Comment: `Ecce` is indeed deictic, so they have the same role.